# Displaying terms of a multiple taxonomy linked to a post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post types called `Product`. Under Products I have custom taxonomies called `colour` and `type`.

Colour has the terms - `Red`, `Yellow`, `White`
Type has the terms - `Type 1`, `Type 2`, `Type 3`.

Product A is colour yellow and is of Type 1.

So I want to display this information.

Please help in how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**get_the_terms()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms). This returns an "Array of term objects on success", so you will have to reference the element in the array, and then the appropriate property of the object. Assuming you want to get the first term name of each:

```
$colourArray = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'colour');
$colour = $colourArray[0]->name;

$typeArray = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'type');
$type = $typeArray[0]->name;
```